# For loop not working in front end but works when executed in backend - VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to loop through the sheets of a book and delete those whose codename contains the string "Sheet" but only clear the cells of all other sheets, other than a "Summary" sheet which I'd like to keep unchanged. The code deletes the intended sheets sometimes, but other times it doesn't. In these cases, I've manually gone into the vba window, ran everything with "Step Into" in the debugger but surprisingly it works completely fine then. Why's this happening? Appreciate your help!

Edit 1: in the instances when the sheets to be deleted don't delete, their cells are cleared, suggesting there is a problem with the InStr statement. I have tried using *Like* as well but to no avail.

Edit 2: the code also works correctly when pressing the play button in the vba window. The instances in which it doesn't work is when I'm running this code using an activex or form button or when I choose a macro to run under the developer tab. I can confirm that the macro does always run when I press the activex button because it's changing some values in the sheet before it reaches the code below.

Edit 3: The sheets that the code seeks to delete have been recently added by another macro. **I think that the codename of the sheets only come into existence once I open vba**, as this seems to be the case: macro doesn't work as intended when executed from button, i open and close the vba editor, and then using the macro via the button works.

Here's the code:

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If InStr(ws.CodeName, "Sheet") > 0 Then
            ws.Delete
        ElseIf ws.CodeName <> "Summary" Then
            ws.Cells.Clear
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: What does "refuses to work" mean???

Comment: The macro runs without any errors but the sheets with codename containing "Sheet" have not been deleted but instead have had their cells cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out myself but will leave this up in case it helps others.

My last edit got me on the right track: the recently added sheets only got their default codename of "Sheetx" when the vba editor is opened. Thus, they don't have any codename if I don't open vba before trying to execute the macro, causing them to not be deleted and instead only have their cells cleared. So, I coded for any sheets with empty codenames to be deleted as well like so, and it worked!

```
If InStr(ws.CodeName, "Sheet") > 0 Or ws.CodeName = "" Then
```